# Naming a chart created with .shapes.chart

Tags: vba, pivot

I've been trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong but I can't find the answer. I've got the following code:

```
Sub CreatePivotChart()

    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    DeleteAllChartObjects

    'setting ws and sh will be done alot here. It's basically making it easy for yourself by making a new (short name):
    Set ws = Worksheets("Analysis")
    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType:=xlColumn, Width:=400, Height:=200)


    'This part to make sure that when there's no cell selected when running the code) within the pivottable, it still works
    Set ch = sh.Chart


    'Acipivot is created as title for the pivottable in sbCreativpivot:
    Set pt = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("Acpivot")
    ch.SetSourceData pt.TableRange1

    'align the chart with the table:
    sh.Top = pt.TableRange1.Top
    sh.Left = pt.TableRange1.Left + pt.TableRange1.Width + 10

End Sub
```

Everything works fine, except I can't name the chart. I've tried several methods that I found online, but none of them seem to work.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
'This part to make sure that when there's no cell selected when running the code) within the pivottable, it still works
Set ch = sh.Chart
With ch
    With .Parent.Name = "test"
    End With
End With
```

But if I then try to reference it like here:

```
Sub EditPivotChart()

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim pf As PivotField

    Set ch = Charts("test")
    Set pt = ch.PivotLayout.PivotTable

    For Each pf In pt.VisibleFields
        pf.Orientation = xlHidden
    Next pf

End Sub
```

I get an error

> vba ran out of memory

Does anyone see what wrong I am doing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try just `ch.Parent.Name = "test"`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But when I reference it like i showed before I now get the error that "subscript is out of range". Any ideas?

Comment: OK so try  `Set ch = Worksheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("test")` and `dim ch as chartobject`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all of the following segment

```
With ch
    With .Parent.Name = "test"
    End With
End With
```

and simply replace it with

```
sh.Name = "test"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I tried, but I now get the error "subscript out of range" when referencing it"

Comment: I think the error has to do with the way the chart is being accessed in editpivotchart sub. 

replace 

Set ch = Charts("test")

with 

set ch = Sheets(sheetname).ChartObjects("test").Chart